# Does the WannaCry Ransomware affect VMs which are connected in Network?

Tags: wannacry

I have a lot of Windows VMs, viz XP, Server 2003, Vista and 7. All of them are in Network and connected to Internet. Will they be affected by WannaCry if not patched ?

Comment: They need to be port forwarded and exposed externally.

Comment: as with non-VMs, it all has to do with the networking

Answer (score 2):

Yes, VMs can be affected as much as "normal" hosts can. It can also affact Linux when you run the code with `wine`.
See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/914623/what-is-the-wanna-cry-ransomwares-possible-impact-on-linux-users

Additional information:
Some derivatives of the malware may detect that you are running these OS's in a virtual maschine and don't go off, but i would not consider this as a comfortable position.